# Get data from electricity meter with IEC62056 protocol via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am developing an android application.I need to get data from meter by optical probe via bluetooth. As I know I should connect to probe with bluetooth and send some request to that for getting the meter values. Please if anybody knows about how to do it .. help me. I used BluetoothSocket,Outputstream and inputstream but no luck!

The probe is an OP-700, and I don't have any documentation/SDK

Code below:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> pairedDeviceArrayList;

TextView textInfo, textStatus,Label1;
ListView listViewPairedDevice;
LinearLayout inputPane;
EditText inputField;
Button btnSend;

ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> pairedDeviceAdapter;
private UUID myUUID;
private final String UUID_STRING_WELL_KNOWN_SPP =
        "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";

ThreadConnectBTdevice myThreadConnectBTdevice;
ThreadConnected myThreadConnected;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    textInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
    textStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);
    listViewPairedDevice = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.pairedlist);

    inputPane = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.inputpane);
    inputField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
    Label1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Label);
    btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(myThreadConnected!=null){

                byte[] bytesToSend = inputField.getText().toString().getBytes();
                myThreadConnected.write(bytesToSend);

            }
        }});

    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH)){
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "FEATURE_BLUETOOTH NOT support",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    //using the well-known SPP UUID
    myUUID = UUID.fromString(UUID_STRING_WELL_KNOWN_SPP);

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Bluetooth is not supported on this hardware platform",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    String stInfo = bluetoothAdapter.getName() + "\n" +
            bluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
    textInfo.setText(stInfo);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    //Turn ON BlueTooth if it is OFF
    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    setup();
}



private void setup() {
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        pairedDeviceArrayList = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            pairedDeviceArrayList.add(device);
        }

        pairedDeviceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pairedDeviceArrayList);
        listViewPairedDevice.setAdapter(pairedDeviceAdapter);

        listViewPairedDevice.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                BluetoothDevice device =
                        (BluetoothDevice) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,
                        "Name: " + device.getName() + "\n"
                                + "Address: " + device.getAddress() + "\n"
                                + "BondState: " + device.getBondState() + "\n"
                                + "BluetoothClass: " + device.getBluetoothClass() + "\n"
                                + "Class: " + device.getClass(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                textStatus.setText("start ThreadConnectBTdevice");
                myThreadConnectBTdevice = new ThreadConnectBTdevice(device);
                myThreadConnectBTdevice.start();
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if(myThreadConnectBTdevice!=null){
        myThreadConnectBTdevice.cancel();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            setup();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "BlueTooth NOT enabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

//Called in ThreadConnectBTdevice once connect successed
//to start ThreadConnected
private void startThreadConnected(BluetoothSocket socket){

    myThreadConnected = new ThreadConnected(socket);
    myThreadConnected.start();
}

/*
ThreadConnectBTdevice:
Background Thread to handle BlueTooth connecting
*/
private class ThreadConnectBTdevice extends Thread {

    private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;
    private final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;


    private ThreadConnectBTdevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        bluetoothDevice = device;

        try {
            bluetoothSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
            textStatus.setText("bluetoothSocket: \n" + bluetoothSocket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean success = false;
        try {
            bluetoothSocket.connect();
            success = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            final String eMessage = e.getMessage();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textStatus.setText("something wrong bluetoothSocket.connect(): \n" + eMessage);
                }
            });

            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(success){
            //connect successful
            final String msgconnected = "connect successful:\n"
                    + "BluetoothSocket: " + bluetoothSocket + "\n"
                    + "BluetoothDevice: " + bluetoothDevice;

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textStatus.setText(msgconnected);

                    listViewPairedDevice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    inputPane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }});

            startThreadConnected(bluetoothSocket);
        }else{
            //fail
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "close bluetoothSocket",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            bluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

/*
ThreadConnected:
Background Thread to handle Bluetooth data communication
after connected
 */
private class ThreadConnected extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket connectedBluetoothSocket;
    private final InputStream connectedInputStream;
    private final OutputStream connectedOutputStream;

    public ThreadConnected(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        connectedBluetoothSocket = socket;
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = socket.getInputStream();
            out = socket.getOutputStream();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        connectedInputStream = in;
        connectedOutputStream = out;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
                String strReceived = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                final String msgReceived = String.valueOf(bytes) +
                        " bytes received:\n"
                        + strReceived;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textStatus.setText(msgReceived);
                    }});

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

                final String msgConnectionLost = "Connection lost:\n"
                        + e.getMessage();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textStatus.setText(msgConnectionLost);
                    }});
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            connectedOutputStream.write(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            textStatus.setText(e.getMessage());
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            connectedBluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            textStatus.setText(e.getMessage());
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think the manufacturer should provide you some sort of SDK (if you're lucky), or at least some documentation on how to use serial comm. What is the manufacturer and the model of the device you want to connect?

Comment: actually the manufacture doesn't give me anything .. but the model of probe is op-700 and my meter and the probe works with IEC-62056-21 protocol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data from optical probe for reading electricity meter in b4a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667215/how-to-get-data-from-optical-probe-for-reading-electricity-meter-in-b4a)

Answer (score 0):

According to your manufacturer [(this is the web of the product)](http://www.optical-probe.de/Optical%20probes/op700.html), explicitly says:

> Please note that additional, specific software is necessary to exchange data between the consumption meter and your peripheral device.

And in operating system, it only mentions Windows OS Desktop ones.

Sorry, there is not much info about that probe. Here, the protocol used to read the electricity meter (IEC-62056-21) is not relevant. The relevant part is how you can communicate with the probe, not the standard that the probe uses for his readings. Regarding your app, the relevant standard is "Serial port communication via Bluetooth"

Go talk with your provider, or your german manufacturer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I'm new to android and I never have worked with bluetooth devices  before so you mean that I can't get data from the probe by my android app or I should just consider "Serial port communication via Bluetooth" instead of IEC62056 protocol..

Comment: the IEC-62056-21 is the protocol used between the probe and the electrical counter. Bluetooth is the protocol between the phone and the probe. You need to use bluetooth, regardless of the IEC-62056-21

Comment: so I can get data from probe via bluetooth.. I've written the codes for communication over Bluetoothsocket but I cant get data from the probe.can you help me if I send my codes?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think so. We need some sort of API, some sort of protocol documentation to know how to work with that particular probe. It would be appreciated if you post your existing code in your original question

Comment: The company I've bought it ,didn't give me any document about it and told that it works without any API

Comment: @mariMir so they lied to you :)